# Image Doesn't Fit

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to make my custom instagram feed with html and css but I have an issue with the images size. An external padding is automatically added and the image doesn't occupy the entire cell.
I'm using bootstrap 5.
[image]

My HTML:

```
<div class="container-fluid" style="padding-left: 5px ; padding-right: 5px;">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-0"></div>
        <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-12">
          <table class="gallery-table" id="gallery-container">
            <tr>
              <td>
                <img src="immagini/questionmark.png" alt="" class="gallery-img" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#image-modal" title="la-citta-pizza">
              </td>
              <td>
                <img src="immagini/questionmark.png" alt="" class="gallery-img" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#image-modal" title="fondane">
              </td>
              <td>
                <img src="immagini/esterna1.jpg" alt="" class="gallery-img" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#image-modal" title="la-citta-pizza1">
              </td>
            </tr>
          </table>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-0"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

My CSS:

```
.gallery-img {
    aspect-ratio: 1/1;    
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    object-fit:cover;
}
```

How I can remove this padding(o?

Comment: As a suggestion, an unordered list might make more sense than a table for an image gallery.

Answer (score 2):

Remove the aspect ratio so that the height no longer depends on the width. Also make the height 100%.

Answer (score 0):

Add position relative to outer and position absolute to inner div's.